# MIPS pipeline stalls with and without forwarding

Tags: mips, pipeline

In the following sequence of MIPS instructions (entire program not shown):

```
DADDUI R1, R1, #-8

BNE R1, R2, Loop
```

I want to confirm the number of stalls required between the two instructions (in context of 5 stage MIPS pipeline - IF, ID/Reg, EX, MEM, WB) with and without forwarding.

My understanding:

(a) If there is no forwarding:

In this case, 2 stalls are required (in cycle 5, R1 can be read in the ID stage for second instruction using split phase access for registers)

(b) If there is forwarding:

In this case, no stalls are required (EX stage on second instruction in cycle 4 can get R1 - 8 forwarded from ALU result for EX stage of first instruction in cycle 3 ; this is assuming branch is checking for equality in EX stage).

Can someone please let me know if the above two answers are correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. In doubt, always make timeline diagrams showing the various pipeline stages. In this case, pictorially, here's what happens:

[image]

Time moves from left to the right. The arrow crossing the table rows in the forwarding version shows where forwarding occurs.

Thus, for case (a), 2 cycles are wasted; for case (b), no cycles are wasted and the pipeline is not stalled.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, and drawing the timing diagram :)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves can you please explain me why didn't you put the stall right after the IF stage in the version without forwarding? I mean, as far as I know, we read from the registers in the ID stage, so we shouldn't put it before DADDUI's WB stage.

Comment: @BaneBojanić You are correct that the register file is read in the ID stage. I guess this is mostly a graphical representation issue, it's just how I learned to draw it. The point is that it stalls in the ID stage, whether or not you draw the stall before or after writing "ID" is a personal preference. If it makes sense for you the other way, you could just write "- -" after IF and only then show ID. Just be consistent on what you do - if you prefer "- - ID", then you're essentially adopting the rule that the "-" precedes a stall in the stage that comes after.