# Hazard Type - Computer Architecture

Tags: cpu-architecture

what the type of hazard is this WAR,RAW,WAW?

```
LW  R2, 0x4000(R30)
LW  R3, 0x8000(R30)
SUB R4, R3, R2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a RAW hazard as you're Writing data into R2 & R3 and then Reading those values in the SUB command.

So (R)ead (A)fter (W)rite

Comment: OH thank you , Got it ... but one more question if we have CPU that use   forwarding and register split then it will STALL 1 cycle time right ?

Comment: Sorry, my recall is only so good - the RAW/WAR/WAW stuff is pretty easy, but the rules - not so much.  See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755071/mips-pipeline-stalls-with-and-without-forwarding